# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException at Star.main(Star.java:14)

Tags: java

I try to print diamond star, but gives the following error.

(Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException 
    at Star.main(Star.java:14).

here is my code.

```
public class Diamond
{
public static void main( String[] args)
{
    int width = 26;
    int row   = 2;
    int mult  = 4;
    int space = ( width - 1 ) / 2;

    for ( int i = 0; i < width; i++ )
    {
        String sp = new String( new char[space] );
        String rw = new String( new char[row] );

        System.out.print(   sp.replace( "\0", " " ) );
        System.out.println( rw.replace( "\0", "*" ) );

        row   += 2 * mult;
        space -= 1 * mult;

        if ( row == width )
            mult = -4;
    }
}}
```

I try to make as that images.

[image]

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear.

Comment: You can't do something like `new char[-1]` which your program is doing at some point.

Comment: So, how I can fix it?

Comment: Stop using negative numbers to make arrays.

Comment: Right after the `for (...) {` add `System.out.println("i = " + i + ", space = " + space + ", row = " + row);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the widest point of the pattern is reached, (`row == width`) `mult` is set to -4 so that the rows get smaller again. But when the last row with 2 stars is finished, (row = 2) 2 + (2*(-4)) = -6. So the next time the loop runs, it tries to create a `char[]` Array that contains -6 elements which of course throws an `NegativeArraySizeException` since it is pretty hard to create a list that contains -6 elements. You should change the exit condition in the for-loop to `for ( int i = 0; i < width && row > 0; i++ )`. This way the loop will not execute if `row` is smaller or equals 0. This also fixes the problem that your loop would have contiuned forever if there wasn't an execption.

Comment: tried a hundred times, but eventually I gave up. I am new to Java. Started last week. and this is a school assignment.

Comment: I made an edit to my post, this should work, I tested it. Sorry for the wrong awnser, it was already pretty late.